# XCode 8 failing to compile Swift 3 code that works on Xcode 9

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, xcode8

The code in question is a bit that comes from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25976909/swift-array-check-if-an-index-exists), and checks whether a given index is available or not.

Specifically, only in **XCode 8.3** does the following issue who up (the code compiles fine in XCode 9 beta. This code is also decidedly Swift 3, and not 4).

[image]

I looked into issues relating to the "missing argument" error, and the typical response is to make sure to include the optional argument. However, in here all 3 are included `optional` `i`, which is the type `Index`.

What am I doing incorrectly with the syntax here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax was changed to this:

```
public func contains(where predicate: (Element) throws -> Bool) rethrows -> Bool
```

Now you should use this one

```
self.indices.contains(where: { (object) -> Bool in
     //make comparison here
})
```

Or

```
self.indices.contains(where: {$0 == "equal to something"})
```

Or you can use something like this:

```
if self.indices.first(where: {$0 == "equal something"}) != nil {
    return self[i]
}else{
    return nil
}
```

BTW, Sets are still have a bool value returned after calling "contains". [Check this](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/CollectionTypes.html)

Comment: Perfect. Thanks for this.