# How Can I Check My Array Index is Out of Range in Swift

Tags: json, swift, swiftui

I do for example this request:

```
mannschaft18teamid = results2.data.table[17].team_id
```

let's say the 17th array element doesn't exist. How can I set the standard value of it if it does not exist?
I want the value to be as a string "not existing".

Maybe like this?:

```
mannschaft18teamid = results2.data.table[17].team_id ?? "not existing"
```

It does not work. The simulator crashes with: `Thread 1: Fatal error: Index out of range`.

It does not even need to set a value. It is also ok if it just ignores that line.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25976909/swift-array-check-if-an-index-exists

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be better to use an optional extension which returns `nil` if the element at the index doesn't exist.

Extension

```
extension Collection where Indices.Iterator.Element == Index {
    subscript (optional index: Index) -> Iterator.Element? {
        return indices.contains(index) ? self[index] : nil
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
mannschaft18teamid = results2.data.table[optional: 17]?.team_id ?? "not existing"
```

Comment: I tried to use this with two swift file. In one this works in the other I get Invalid redeclaration of 'subscript(optional:)' What do I need to change?

Comment: Declare it just once, use it everywhere.

Answer (score 4):

If `results2.data.table` is an array, try this:

```
let index = 17
if results2.data.table.indices.contains(index) {
    mannschaft18teamid = results2.data.table[index].team_id
} else {
    mannschaft18teamid = "not existing"
}
```

You're getting the `Index out of range` error, so you should use `indices.contains(index)` to check if the index exists. More info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25976909/swift-array-check-if-an-index-exists).

Answer (score 4):

If you want this syntax, you could extend `RandomAccessCollection` and implement a subscribt that returns an optional value from the array:

```
extension RandomAccessCollection {
    subscript(index: Index) -> Element? {
        self.indices.contains(index) ? (self[index] as Element) : nil
    }
}
```

This way you could do something like this:

```
let arr = ["a", "b", "c"]
print(arr[99] ?? "not existing") // "not existing"
```

You'd have to be careful to make sure that an `Optional` type is inferred from the context, like with `??` or with optional chaining `arr[99]?.prop`, because the following would still behave normally, i.e. will fail with `Index out of range`:

```
let v = arr[99] // error
```

---

Alternatively, you can define a subscript with a default value (like `Dictionary` does):

```
extension RandomAccessCollection {
    subscript(index: Index, default defaultValue: @autoclosure () -> Element) -> Element {
        self.indices.contains(index) ? self[index] : defaultValue()
    }
}
```

```
let arr = [1,2,3]
print(arr[9, default: 99]) // 99
```

Answer (score 2):

If you don't need it to set it any value you should probably use a guard statement to get the element at index.

```
guard results2.data.table.count >= 18 else {
    // Bad path, early exit scope
    return 
}

// Happy path, keep going
mannschaft18teamid = results2.data.table[17].team_id
```

But you should keep in mind, guards are for early exit from scope in unexpected situations so anything after that will not be executed. If you want execution to keep going then you should use if let:

```
if let results2.data.table.count >= 18 {
    // Index exists, do stuff
   mannschaft18teamid = results2.data.table[17].team_id
}
```

If you want to keep using nil coalescing operator (??) to provide a default value, then you should implement an extension to Collections to safely access items. You can read other answers or refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30593673/4233703) answer.

Comment: The `Index out of range` error happens when the array doesn't contain that index -- not if it's nil or not.

Comment: @aheze You are absolutely correct, my bad. I corrected it.